# Compare the string in one row to the same string in all other rows and register the difference, performance issues with pandes

Tags: python, pandas, string, performance, loops

I have a data frame of 700k records in pandas. Because of an backlog issue we need to compare the string in one row to the same string in all other rows. This comparison needs to check if there is a difference of one character in both strings. If a match is found register the rows that contain almost the same value.

And return the following output:

```
[0] []
[1] [2,100]
[2] [1,100]
..
```

The following code works, however is very slow with 700k records.

```
def match(str1, str2):
    # Return true if one character is different
    difference = False
    for char1, char2 in zip(str1, str2):
        if char1 != char2:
            if difference:
                return False
            difference = True
    return difference

def func(text):
    matches = DF.apply(lambda x: match(text, x['String']), axis = 1)
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(matches) if x]

DFtwo = DF.apply(lambda row: func(row['String']), axis = 1)
```

Are there any solution on how to speed this up in Pandas? Most answers on stack overflow focus on speeding up numeric calculation but no string comparison. Any solutions with different code in python also appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly provide sample data, with expected output. is the output going to be a dataframe/series/sequence ? while at it, list comprehensions are very fast when string manipulation is involved

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use one liner:

```
count = sum(1 for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2) if a != b)
```

which will simply return the number of differences in two strings, the time used by this one liner for random data was slightly worse than your method (several seconds on 1M tries). However, in case the strings are of different length, you can compare the length of the strings `diff = abs(len(seq1) - len(seq2))` first, which might save you some time. Besides that, there does not seem to be much improvement, trying out your code it runs fast and time complexity of your code is very low.

Yet you can take a look at [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html), functions like `get_close_matches` might come handy, but I have no knowledge about efficiency of this lib, neither usefulness for you.